# set rows in Pandas dataframe to NaN starting from where index is equal to certain value

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas dataframe such as this:

```
                  A  
year
2018-01-01        10
2018-01-02        15
2018-01-03        10
2018-01-04        19
2018-01-05        30
2018-01-06        23
2018-01-07        10
2018-01-08        56
2018-01-09        20
2018-01-10        10
```

How to set values of `A` to `NaN` starting from where index is equal to a certain value, for example `2018-01-07`:

```
                  A  
year
2018-01-01        10
2018-01-02        15
2018-01-03        10
2018-01-04        19
2018-01-05        30
2018-01-06        23
2018-01-07        NaN
2018-01-08        NaN
2018-01-09        NaN
2018-01-10        NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
In [851]: df.loc['2018-01-07':] = np.nan

In [852]: df
Out[852]:
               A
year
2018-01-01  10.0
2018-01-02  15.0
2018-01-03  10.0
2018-01-04  19.0
2018-01-05  30.0
2018-01-06  23.0
2018-01-07   NaN
2018-01-08   NaN
2018-01-09   NaN
2018-01-10   NaN
```

Comment: This approach applies to whole dataframe in case there're more columns than `A`. How to make this apply specifically to `A`?

Comment: `df.loc['2018-01-07':, 'A'] = ..`

Answer (score 3):

Below code gives you the desired result:

```
    import numpy as np
df.set_index("d", inplace=True)
df['A'].loc['2015-01-08':]=np.nan


             A
d   
2015-01-01  0.0
2015-01-02  1.0
2015-01-03  2.0
2015-01-04  3.0
2015-01-05  4.0
2015-01-06  5.0
2015-01-07  6.0
2015-01-08  NaN
2015-01-09  NaN
2015-01-10  NaN
```

If this is what you want, please select the answer.

Thanks